# Ubuntu12.04 hotspot creation problem

Tags: 12.04, networking, hot-spot

I am doing this
Creating a wireless network through EDIT CONNECTIONS, with wireless security as 128 bit paraphrase and shared to other computers.

Then I am creating a network through create new wireless network
I do not get any wirelsss network on my device.

Then I do this

```
# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
# sudo aptitude update
# aptitude install ap-hotspot
# ap-hotspot configure
# ap-hotspot start
```

for few times my mobile detected the network but it couldn't connected. It tried to get IP and authenicating. So I tried to stop and create another. From then it never detects a hotspot too.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Is your mobile an Android phone ? Android cannot connect to Ad-Hoc networks, only infastructure.

To create an Ad-Hoc connection, for network sharing, do this.

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base

sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq
```

Create a new wireless network using networkmanager, make sure it is an Ad-Hoc network and tick "Automatically connect if this network is in range".

In the ipv4 section, select "shared with other computers".

Now, from network manager menu, disable then enable networking (to restart network manager).

Now try connecting to it from another PC, running either Windows or Linux or Mac for that matter. Does that connect ?

This is how I do it and it works for me.

Here is the link I got the information from :

[Internet connection sharing with Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)